With a Next.js application, how can I prevent or detect failures due to incomplete file loading?
I'm currently working with a Next.js-based frontend system using fairly vanilla configuration options.
Recently I've run into some issues where the application is effectively broken to end users because one or more of the JS/CSS files hasn't loaded properly. For example, a page isn't usable because the key CSS file doesn't load, and the page looks mangled. Or the user's browser fails to load an incremental JS file, and so when they click into a different tab, the tab superficially loads, but (because the JS file was requested and didn't pull correctly from the server) doesn't actually work.
Is there a way to improve this robustness?
For example, is there a way to hint Next.js to have Webpack bundle everything into one file? (So that when it fails, the user is implicitly prompted to reload, and when that succeeds they'll get everything.) Or is there a plug-in that more proactively checks for load failures and can retry in the case where a chunk of JS/CSS fails to pull from the server?
I saw a variety of standalone tools like RequireJS (http://requirejs.org), but my understanding is that those basically conflict with things that the Next.js framework is already doing to package and bundle files together.
